# Automatically upload local file even if it's changed in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am looking for a solution that allows the browser to continually upload a local file initially selected by the user, even if that file is edited. I have a solution that works in chrome, but Firefox stops uploading it once the file is edited. That code is pasted below.

```
function readSingleFile(e) {
  var readers = new Array();
  setInterval(function () {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  readers.push(new FileReader());
  readers[readers.length-1].onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    // Display file content
    displayContents(contents);
    console.log(contents);
  };
  readers[readers.length-1].readAsText(file);
}, 5000);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML += contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File objects are "live" in Chrome - change the file length and the value of `fileObject.length` changes when read again, reading the file's `lastModified` property returns the most recent modification date and time, and  reading the file's content returns the updated content (as stated in the post).

File objects are **not** live in Firefox at this time. The value returned by reading `fileObject.length` remains unchanged even if the file length has changed, and reading the file's `lastModified` property returns the time stamp from when the file reference was created. Attempting to read an updated file causes the file reader's `onerror` handler to be called with  "NotReadableError: File could not be read" as argument.

The [File API specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) is still an editors draft at Feb 1 2019. The [File Interface section](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-section) talks of taking a snapshot of file state on disk (name, length and last modified date):

> If a File object is a reference to a byte sequence originating from a file on disk, then its snapshot state should be set to the state of the file on disk at the time the File object is created.

and follows it with the following note (emphasis mine):

> Note: This is a non-trivial requirement to implement for user agents, and is thus **not a must but a should** [RFC2119]. User agents should endeavor to have a File object’s snapshot state set to the state of the underlying storage on disk at the time the reference is taken. If the file is modified on disk following the time a reference has been taken, the File's snapshot state will differ from the state of the underlying storage. User agents **may** use modification time stamps and other mechanisms to maintain snapshot state, **but** this is left as an implementation detail.

My reading of this is that Firefox, at this stage of the standard's development, is not required to implement Chrome's behavior to be "compliant". At the same time I would not be surprised if Firefox  adopted the draft proposal at some time in the future - or chose not to.

In conclusion I rather doubt there *is* a Firefox solution for your requirement at this time.